# Selenium Webdriver - cant click on md dialog element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.5/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.5/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cdk-overlay-container">
<div class="cdk-overlay-backdrop cdk-overlay-dark-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing">
</div>
<div class="cdk-global-overlay-wrapper" style="justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
<div id="cdk-overlay-4" class="cdk-overlay-pane" dir="ltr" style="position: static; width: 500px; pointer-events: auto;">
<md-dialog-container class="mat-dialog-container" role="dialog">
<cdk-focus-trap>
<!--template bindings={}-->
<div tabindex="0">
</div>
<div class="cdk-focus-trap-content">
<!--template bindings={}-->
<app-dialog _nghost-wcd-65="">
<h1 _ngcontent-wcd-65="" md-dialog-title="" class="mat-dialog-title">
Confirm
</h1>
<hr _ngcontent-wcd-65="">
<div _ngcontent-wcd-65="" md-dialog-content="" class="mat-dialog-content">
Are you sure to become Tech Leader of 6757657?
</div>
<hr _ngcontent-wcd-65="" class="bottomLine">
<div _ngcontent-wcd-65="" class="bottomSection mat-dialog-actions" md-dialog-actions="">
<button _ngcontent-wcd-65="" class="btn">
Yes
</button>
<button _ngcontent-wcd-65="" class="btn" md-dialog-close="" type="button" aria-label="Close dialog">
No
</button>
</div>
</app-dialog>
</div>
<!--template bindings={}-->
<div tabindex="0">
</div>
</cdk-focus-trap>
</md-dialog-container>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I do not have any idea why it does not want to click on 'Yes' button on the displayed dialog.
My code looks like this:

```
String parentWindowHandler = SeleniumExecutor.getDriver().getWindowHandle(); 
        String subWindowHandler = null;

        Set<String> handles = 
SeleniumExecutor.getDriver().getWindowHandles(); 
        Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
        }

SeleniumExecutor.getDriver().switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);

        projectPage.confirmAddingTechLead();

        SeleniumExecutor.getDriver().switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
}

public void confirmAddingTechLead(){
projectsPageLocators.yes_techLead.click();}
```

Don't know why "yes" element is not located, I think my locator is fine, it has to be something with handeling the dialog window but i tried few different approaches and I always get following error:

> rg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/md-dialog-container/cdk-focus-trap/div[2]/app-dialog/div[2]/button[1]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.98)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.28.455520
>   (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 4.07 seconds For
>   documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13
>   -0700' System info: host: 'LPACZEK-RZE', ip: '10.10.32.72', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_121' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.28.455520
>   (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),
>   userDataDir=C:\Users\lpaczek\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir2256_6186},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   version=57.0.2987.98, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}] Session ID:
>   1f5bf251b3097b95ce337030cad3fab8
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/md-dialog-container/cdk-focus-trap/div[2]/app-dialog/div[2]/button[1]}
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:368)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:473)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getCoordinates(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.MouseAction.getActionLocation(MouseAction.java:51)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveMouseAction.perform(MoveMouseAction.java:39)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.CompositeAction.perform(CompositeAction.java:50)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:373) 
>   at
>   pages.executors.ProjectPage.confirmAddingTechLead(ProjectPage.java:99)
>   at steps.EditProjectSteps.iClickYes(EditProjectSteps.java:138)   at
>   ✽.And I click
>   Yes(C:/Users/lpaczek/Documents/prome/src/test/resources/Task1/EditProject.feature:32)

Comment: Why did you tagged this question with `jQuery`?

Comment: Share `HTML` or `URL` of page. Also show us how you tried those `few different approaches`

Comment: Sory I am a newbie, was not even sure but I add couple lines of code.

Comment: Can you try relative `XPath` like `//button[normalize-space(text())='Yes']`?

Comment: @Ionut "[Not enough jQuery](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Hk1mt-RKYLc/UOkxShm6NrI/AAAAAAAACqo/LVmqHOfWV7g/s1600/20091116-so-large.gif)" taken too far?

Comment: @Andersson
Thank you m8, could you explain why my previous xpath
"html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/md-dialog-container/cdk-focus-trap/div[2]/app-dialog/div[2]/button[1]"
didnt work?

Comment: You shouldn't use absolute XPath as you get it from page that has been already rendered. Some elements could be generated dynamically with `JavaScript`. When you get page with your code those elements are not yet created, so your XPath` won't return required element